# Impact drivers and shredded screw heads

Tags: drill

I just bought an impact driver. When I use it on a 2 inch wood screw into hard wood, after drilling a pilot hole, I seem to shred the screw head.  What are the tricks to using impact driver?

Comment: Avoid Phillips-head screws?

Comment: Drill larger pilot holes.

Comment: Proper driver tip for screw, but replace it as soon as it starts to spread a head.  I keep at least 20 tips on hand when starting a project.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume a few things and you can correct me if I'm mistaken. I'm guessing you're using phillips screws (not pozi-drive, nothing fancy like torx). I'm also assuming you've got a good quality driver bit, that hasn't been used too long.

So, a few suggestions:

- make sure you're screwing directly in line with the screw. Any angle variance is bad.
- get behind the impact driver and push. You need to maintain a good amount of pressure.
- buy high-quality screws... I've had particularly bad results from big box gold screws. The exterior grade ones (gray paint) seem much better. Most of the name-brand ones (as opposed to the 'house brands') are better.
- also consider alternate driver heads -- torx, robertson, pozi-drive, unidrive. (The alternate heads frequently go hand-in-hand with better products, as well.)
- if your bit is worn out from a few too many off-angle screeching spins, throw it out.